# how to get unique column values Ruby CSV array

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a ruby csv object as follows

```
[14] pry(main)> $importStocks[0..3]
=> [#<CSV::Row "Symbol":"B" "Name":"Barnes Group, Inc." "Exchange":"NYSE" "Sector":"Industrial" "Industry":"Industrial Suppliers" "SCTR":"76.7" "Universe":"sml" "Close":"64.880" "Volume":"112191">,
 #<CSV::Row "Symbol":"BA" "Name":"Boeing Co." "Exchange":"NYSE" "Sector":"Industrial" "Industry":"Aerospace" "SCTR":"1.8" "Universe":"lrg" "Close":"309.000" "Volume":"18769578">,
 #<CSV::Row "Symbol":"BAB" "Name":"Invesco Taxable Municipal Bond ETF" "Exchange":"NYSE" "Sector":"" "Industry":"" "SCTR":"33.3" "Universe":"etf" "Close":"32.180" "Volume":"151304">,
 #<CSV::Row "Symbol":"BABA" "Name":"Alibaba Group Holding Ltd." "Exchange":"NYSE" "Sector":"Consumer Discretionary" "Industry":"Broadline Retailers" "SCTR":"88.7" "Universe":"mid" "Close":"222.370" "Volume":"10031812">]
```

I want to get the column Exchange values only. how do i do it? as the map function does not work?

```
[15] pry(main)> $importStocks.map(&:Exchange)
NoMethodError: undefined method `Exchange' for #<CSV::Row:0x0000000005aa76e8>
from (pry):15:in `map'
[16] pry(main)> $importStocks.map(&:"Exchange")
NoMethodError: undefined method `Exchange' for #<CSV::Row:0x0000000005aa76e8>
from (pry):16:in `map'
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages. Instead of showing us object dumps, we need the minimal code and required input data that duplicates the problem, along with your required output. As is your question is off-topic because we need that detail. Ruby's [CSV documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) is quite thorough; I'd recommend looking at the example code closely.

Comment: Be careful using globals like `$importStocks`. You're opening your code up for hard to diagnose bugs with globals. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide is a good thing to read multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSV::Row` accepts message `field` with field name as an argument. [CSV::Row.field](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-field)

```
exchange_values = $import_stocks.map { |row| row.field("Exchange") }
```

Comment: Why downvote? If you explain, will be happy to fix or remove if answer is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Let's first create a CSV file. To simplify, I've included only four of your fields. I also changed the value of `"Exchange"` in one row from `"NYSE"` to `"FTSE"`. Because the value of one of the `"Name"` fields contains a comma, I've made the column separator a semicolon, but there are of course other options. A comma could be used if the entries in the `name` column were enclosed in quotes.

```
fname = 't.csv'

File.write fname, <<~END
Symbol;Name;Exchange;Sector
B;Barnes Group, Inc.;NYSE;Industrial
BA;Boeing Co.;FTSE;Industrial
BAB;Invesco Taxable Municipal Bond ETF;NYSE;
BABA;Alibaba Group Holding Ltd.;NYSE;Consumer Discretionary
END
  #=> 200
```

We now simply use [CSV::read](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read) with the options `headers: true` and `col_sep: ';'` to read the file into a [CSV::Table](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) object:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read(fname, headers: true, col_sep: ';')
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:5>
```

and use [CSV::table#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D) to extract  the `"Exchange"` column:

```
csv["Exchange"] 
  #=> ["NYSE", "FTSE", "NYSE", "NYSE"]
```